# C++ template : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am currently designing a templated Vector2 class, for my game engine.

In order to keep everything tidy, I have been separating the function declarations and definitions. This was working fine with the constructors, however, I get the following error when trying to the same with a static function:

```
error C2244: 'spl::Vector2<T>::Dot' : unable to match function definition to an existing  declaration
1>          definition
1>          'T spl::Vector2<T>::Dot(const spl::Vector2<L> &,const spl::Vector2<R> &)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'T spl::Vector2<T>::Dot(const spl::Vector2<L> &,const spl::Vector2<R> &)'
```

What I am finding unusual is that despite the fact that the declaration and definition are identical, the compiler fails to match them.

Here is my Vector2 class:

```
// The Vector2 Class
template <typename T> 
class Vector2{
public:

    // Constructor
    Vector2 ();
    Vector2 (T Value);
    Vector2 (T XAxis, T YAxis);

    // Static Functions
    template <typename L, typename R>
    static T Dot (const Vector2 <L>& LHS, const Vector2 <R>& RHS);

    // Variables
    T x, y;
};
```

And here is the function declaration that sits just below it:

```
// Return The Dot Product Of Two Vectors
template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
T Vector2 <T>::Dot (const Vector2 <L>& LHS, const Vector2 <R>& RHS){

    T xAxis = (T) LHS.x * (T) RHS.x;
    T yAxis = (T) LHS.y * (T) RHS.y;

    return (xAxis + yAxis);
}
```

If anyone knows why this error is being thrown and how to fix it, I will be forever in your debt.

P.S. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax needs to be:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename L, typename R>
T Vector2 <T>::Dot (const Vector2 <L>& LHS, const Vector2 <R>& RHS){

    T xAxis = (T) LHS.x * (T) RHS.x;
    T yAxis = (T) LHS.y * (T) RHS.y;

    return (xAxis + yAxis);
}
```